# ZABBIX AWX, sync invetory

Tags: ansible, zabbix, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx, zabbix-api

Is possible sync the inventory of **Ansible tower (AWX)** running in containers with **Zabbix** inventory?

Any code or playbook to make this appreciate a lot!

Comment: What is the purpose? With a little imagination we can create anything, if the goal is known and doable.

Comment: i search for a code if exist

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.. You need to fetch hosts from yous inventory of ansible tower and use zabbix modules to update hosts on your zabbix server.

here are the list of [modules for zabbix](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/zabbix/index.html)

and here is the module to [create/update/delete hosts on zabbix](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/zabbix/zabbix_host_module.html#ansible-collections-community-zabbix-zabbix-host-module)

You playbooks should execute community.zabbix.zabbix_host module in loop with_inventory_hostnames from a specific group or all hosts in the inventory.